# How to Fetch or extract value from Div tag using Jmeter

Tags: html, xpath, expression, jmeter, extractor

I want to fetch OTP value(123456) from Div tag, as it changes every time.
    How can i do this in Jmeter?
    I have some idea that, it can done by **xpath extractor & reguler expression**..but doesn't successful in dong so..  Please help me.
    Code Sample is like this.

```
<div id="messages">
<div class="section clearfix"> 
<div class="messages status"> 
<h2 class="element-invisible">Status message</h2> OTP has been sent to your registered email id.  OTP is 123456</div></div></div>


I want OTP value in a variable...so that i can use that dynamically.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Regular expression extractor as a post processor like,

[image]

Later you can use that value anywhere using ${OTP_val} variable